# How do I hide/show HTML elements based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs as you see in the picture each one of them display: block on a specific screen size and the other two div s display: none so what I want to do is that remove the id in each  div depending on if this div has a css ( display :none ) because having the same id make my navbar don't work good when I change screen size ,it just work fine on the first div, I had tried to do it but it didn't work

```html
<section class="mynavicon">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="navselect active">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="service">SERVICES</a>
        <li>
          <li><a href="#" data-scroll="my-art">MY ART</a>
            <li>
              <li><a href="#" data-scroll="about">ABOUT</a>
                <li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-scroll="contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
                    <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="container art clearfix" id="my-art">
  <div class="collection">
    <div class="bg1"><img src="img/17.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg2"><img src="img/19.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg3"><img src="img/20.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg4"><img src="img/15.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg5"><img src="img/21.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container art2" id="my-art">
  <div class="row collection2">
    <div class="b1 col-md-4 offset-sm-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0  mb-3 col-sm-12"><img src="img/38.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b2 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/31.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b3 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/37.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b4 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/33.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b5 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/34.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b6 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/36.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container art3" id="my-art">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img1 col-10 offset-1">
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="img/28.jpg">
        <img src="img/25.jpg">
        <img src="img/26.jpg">
        <img src="img/27.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="next arrow" id="arrow-rit"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
      <div class="prev arrow" id="arrow-lft"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the future, please copy+paste your code into the question itself. It's much easier to debug code when we can manipulate it, test it, etc. That said, your problem is that you can't have repeated ID's in HTML. Because of this, any JavaScript that searches for an element by ID will immediately "finish" after finding the first one, because it assumes there are no more on the page. You should be using *classes* instead.

Comment: "_having the same id make my navebar don't work good_"
What do you mean? Do you mean it doesn't work because it only works with the first `<div>`? What is the symptoms?

Comment: there is one link on my navbar ( my-art ) i want it to navigate to each div according to my screen size so i know that id is used to make my navbar go to a specific section on my page so how i do this when i want the same link on my navbar navigate to the three divs when they displayed on my screen

Comment: i put the same id name to my three div to make my navbar link (my-art ) navigate to them according to which one is displayed block in my screen but it just work fine with my first div the other two when i click the link on my navbar it take me to the top of my page

Comment: No ya 3am @MohamedNagehOtafy **id should be unique** don't use same id for more than one element like [dotnetcarpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52032133/3385827) said in his answer

Comment: check my answer ya @MohamedNagehOtafy

Answer (score 2):

You can not have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute in HTML.

Only the first unique `id` counts and the browser will ignore the rest.

THIS IS IMPORTANT - YOU CAN NOT HAVE THE SAME ID ON MULTIPLE ELEMENTS.

Using id as anchor in a page will only work for the first, since the next id's will be ignored.

Fist remove or move any CSS you have the `#my-art` selector, since you will make that a parent to all previous `id="my-art"` sections. You might be able to move the styling to `.container` (although the name is ubiquitous). `.art__container` might be a better class name.

```html
<section class="mynavicon">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="navselect active">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="service">SERVICES</a>
        <li>
          <li><a href="#" data-scroll="my-art">MY ART</a>
            <li>
              <li><a href="#" data-scroll="about">ABOUT</a>
                <li>
                  <li><a href="#" data-scroll="contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
                    <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="my-art">
  <div class="container art clearfix">
    <div class="collection">
      <div class="bg1"><img src="img/17.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="bg2"><img src="img/19.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="bg3"><img src="img/20.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="bg4"><img src="img/15.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="bg5"><img src="img/21.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container art2">
    <div class="row collection2">
      <div class="b1 col-md-4 offset-sm-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0  mb-3 col-sm-12"><img src="img/38.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="b2 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/31.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="b3 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/37.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="b4 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/33.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="b5 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/34.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="b6 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/36.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container art3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="img1 col-10 offset-1">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src="img/28.jpg">
          <img src="img/25.jpg">
          <img src="img/26.jpg">
          <img src="img/27.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="next arrow" id="arrow-rit"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
        <div class="prev arrow" id="arrow-lft"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ok how i make my navebar work on my three divs when my screen size change

Comment: Use `media-queries` which I assume you already are? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: i try to make things easy for other to understand not because i am lazy

Comment: ya i use media-query but how this going to help me to do that

Comment: Then you should copy/paste your code, so others can copy/paste your code. From an image that is not possible. Instead of colorful circles you could write titles to each code section.

Comment: Post your code and I'll show you

Comment: ok i put the my navbar code and my three div code

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss what [dotnetCarpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52032133/3385827) said in his answer and use the html structure suggested by him.. and about media queries you can use it like this

```css
.art2 , .art3{
  display : none;
}


@media screen and (max-width : 780px){  /* width less than 780px */
  .art, .art3{
    display : none;
  }
  .art2{
    display : block;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width : 500px){  /* width less than 500px */
  .art, .art2{
    display : none;
  }
  .art3{
    display : block;
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="mynavicon">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="navselect active">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="service">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="my-art">MY ART</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-scroll="contact-us">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="container art clearfix">
  <div class="collection">
    <div class="bg1"><img src="img/17.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg2"><img src="img/19.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg3"><img src="img/20.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg4"><img src="img/15.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="bg5"><img src="img/21.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container art2">
  <div class="row collection2">
    <div class="b1 col-md-4 offset-sm-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0  mb-3 col-sm-12"><img src="img/38.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b2 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/31.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b3 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/37.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b4 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/33.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b5 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/34.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="b6 offset-sm-3 col-md-4 mb-3 offset-lg-0 offset-md-0 col-sm-12"><img src="img/36.jpg" style="max-width:100%;max-height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container art3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img1 col-10 offset-1">
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="img/28.jpg">
        <img src="img/25.jpg">
        <img src="img/26.jpg">
        <img src="img/27.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="next arrow" id="arrow-rit"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
      <div class="prev arrow" id="arrow-lft"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** you can change `(max-width : 780px)` and `(max-width : 500px)` to whatever width you want .. and don't forget to close `</li>`

Comment: i did that but when i click on my navbar to scroll to this it keep going to the top of my page , so it didn't work

Comment: @MohamedNagehOtafy use dotnetCarpenter HTML instead of yours

Comment: i use it and it work just fine , but i have another problem face me
when i scroll down my website keep scroll up by it self what do you think the problem

Comment: @MohamedNagehOtafy I think the problem will be in the javascript code.. 1-check the scroll plugin you'r using  . 2- if you have a custom scroll event check it